# django-1.3 login form +context_processor

Tags: django

Django-1.3
I need to render a login form on every page.
I'm confused, always used the "generic view 'django.contrib.views.auth.login' straight into my urls.py.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could solve this...

One is a template tag that sits in a layout that all of your other pages inherit which adds the form.

Another is a context processor that adds the form to the context which would be available on every page.

Hope that helps you out.